# how to add one or more clone in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery and im using laravel framework. I want to add courses after filling first course by user. [image]

When user click on add more course button.it will create new clone make sure that add more course button will be removed from first course and set to second course and same apply for newly created course and add more button should removed from second course and set to third course . i have hrml code.

```
enter code here
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="heading">
                <h4>Courses Offred <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-hidden="true" style="display:none">&times;</button></h4>
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Course  Title</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div> 
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Fees</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div> 
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Web Link</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div> 
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Course Detail</span>
                         <textarea  class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10 txtarea" rows="5" placeholder="Add Your Course Detail"></textarea>
                     </div>
                 </div> 
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Course Type</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div>  
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Course Duration</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Location</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Entry Requirement</span>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="property-type">
                        <span class="property-class">Certificates</span>
                         <textarea  class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10 txtarea" rows="5" placeholder="Add Your Certificates"></textarea>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="add-more-class ">
                          <div class="btn-save">
                            <button class="btn btn-info">Add More Course</button>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>                       
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

In heading tag there is close button.and it should visible in second course and make validation user can't add more than five course. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clean up your html markup a little bit and your work and code will be more easy and understable.
1-seperate Add More Course button from form-content.
2-give proper class to form container.
3-write a simple code and done.

### Modified HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 forms-container">
    <div class="row single-form">
        <div class="heading">
            <h4>Courses Offred</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Course  Title</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Fees</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Web Link</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Course Detail</span>
                <textarea class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10 txtarea" rows="5" placeholder="Add Your Course Detail"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Course Type</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Course Duration</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Location</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Entry Requirement</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" placeholder="Enter value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="property-type">
                <span class="property-class">Certificates</span>
                <textarea class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10 txtarea" rows="5" placeholder="Add Your Certificates"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
                Please fill all the fields.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="add-more-class text-center ">
                <button class="btn btn-info add-more-course">Add More Course</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="add-more-class ">
                <button class="btn btn-info pull-right save-and-continue">Save and continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var count = 0;
$('.add-more-course').click(function() {
    if (count < 4) {
        /* clone single .single-form container */
        var $new_form = $(this).parents('.forms-container').find('.single-form').first().clone(true);

        /* clear form data if any field is filled */
        $new_form.find('input,textarea').val("");

        /* remove heading text and enable close button */
        $new_form
            .find('.heading h4')
            .text("")
            .append('<button type="button" class="close">X</button>')
            .end()
            .find('.alert').css('display','none');

        /* append it before add more course button */
        $(this).parents('.forms-container').find('.single-form').last().after($new_form)
        count++;
    }
});

$('.forms-container').on('click', '.single-form .close', function() {
    $(this).parents('.single-form').remove();
    count--;
});

$('.forms-container').on('click', '.save-and-continue', function(){
    var $form_container = $(this).parents('.forms-container'),
        is_error = false;
    $form_container.find('.single-form').each(function(ind, form){
        var $form = $(form);
        $form.find('input,textarea').each(function(ind,ele){
            if($(ele).val() === "" || $(ele).val() === undefined){
                $form.find('.alert').css('display','block');
                is_error = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }); 

    if(!is_error) {
        // write ajax call or anything else what you want on success
    }
});
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you. Absolutely working fine. Brijesh can you please provide validation for this code. It will be more helpful for me. Once again Thanks a lot :)

Comment: your welcome @kunal, I am glad it helped you.
For validation I am giving simple example to check weather any field is left blank on the basis of that we will show alert box with message.
use this bootstrap alert and submit button below certificates section.

 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
                    Please fill all the fields.
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-info submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

Comment: and add this js code to check validation

 $('.forms-container').on('click', '.single-form .submit', function(){
        var $form = $(this).parents('.single-form'),
            is_error = false;
        $form.find('input,textarea').each(function(ind,ele){
            if($(ele).val() === "" || $(ele).val() === undefined){
                $form.find('.alert').css('display','block');
                is_error = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(!is_error) {
           // success event task
        }
    });
it will show errror box on submit.

Comment: dear brijesh i have two buttons one is for add more course and second is at right bottom of page i.e save and continue. i want validation something like when user clicks on (save and continue ) button it validate all the fields of all clone that user have inserted. here is my save and continue button.     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="additional">
                     <div class="btn-save">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save And Coutinue </button></div> </div> </div></div>

Comment: Ok. I got that. You need one single save and continue button for all instances of form. On click of that you will validate all the forms.
Correct?

Comment: yes exactly brijesh. add course button should be there for add courses. once users hit (save and continue ) button it will validate all the fields

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the script that you wanted:

Updated script:

```
var courseCtr = 1;
console.log('course counter: ' + courseCtr);
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn', function() {

    if (courseCtr === 5) {
        return false;
    }

    var $row = $(this).closest('div.heading').parent();
    var $parent = $row.parent();
    var $clone = $row.clone();
    if ($clone.find('.heading .close').length === 1) {
        $clone.find('.heading .close').remove();
    }
    $clone.find('.heading h4').after('<button class="close">X</button>')
    $clone.find(':input').val('');
    $clone.find('textarea').val('');
    $row.find('.heading div').last().remove();

  //  $clone.find('.heading h4').remove();

    $parent.append($clone);
    courseCtr++;
    console.log('course counter: ' + courseCtr);
})

$(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
    var $buttonClone = $(this).parent().find('div').last().clone();
    $(this).parents('.row').prev().find('div.heading').append($buttonClone);
    $(this).parents('.row').remove();
    courseCtr--;
    console.log('course counter: ' + courseCtr);
})
```

UPDATED FIDDLE: [SEE FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/anv8yhou/8/)

Comment: thank you four that works fine. here is one more problem when user add new course in second  heading i want Cross button when user clicks on cross button it will be deleted that clone. Please provide me solution for this

Comment: i have updated the fiddle.... i don't know where you want to add the close button though..so i just inserted it after the `<hr>` tag

Comment: w8 there's a bug.. forgot to return the deleted button class

Comment: four it removes my whole page. its not working properly :(

Comment: please help me :( i think the div u mentioned in click event on close. i think there is problem. it working right on fiddle. but when i put whole html code in jsfiddle it also not working overhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127425/discussion-between-kunal-and-four).

Answer (score -1):

you can get help from below code,

```
jQuery(document).delegate('a.add-record', 'click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();    
     var content = jQuery('#sample_table tr'),
     size = jQuery('#tbl_posts >tbody >tr').length + 1,
     element = null,    
     element = content.clone();
     element.attr('id', 'rec-'+size);
     element.find('.delete-record').attr('data-id', size);
     element.appendTo('#tbl_posts_body');
     element.find('.sn').html(size);
   });
```

on click of add more button you need to create clone of first form of parent div and append with container.

[Dynamically Add and Remove rows/html form in a Table Using jquery](http://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/jquery-tutorials/dynamically-add-remove-rows-table-using-jquery/)